Type assertion in JSDoc VScode
/**
 * @typedef Animal
 * @property {string} noise
*/

/**
 * @typedef Duck
 * @property {string} noise
 * @property {number} wings
*/

/**
 * @param {Animal} a
 */
function TestAnimal(a) { console.log(a.noise) }

// 0. warning
TestAnimal({ noise: 'quack', wings: 2 })  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'wings' does not exist in type 'Animal'.ts(2353)

// 1. multiple
const bear = { noise: 'roar', feet: 4 }
TestAnimal(bear)

// 2. single, extra parentheses
TestAnimal(/** @type {Animal} */({ noise: 'meow', tails: 1 }))

Are these the only 2 ways to type assert without warning in VSCode? I find both unwieldy and something closer to (0) would be much preferred.
Another solution I've come across is
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *   noise: string
 *   [others: string]: any
 * }} Animal
*/

but it's less than ideal since I have to apply it to all typedef I might extend from and defeats its purpose in some cases
I dont want to use
/** @typedef {Duck | Bear | Cat} Animal */

either, since this requires Animal to keep track of everything that extends it and doesn't allow other users to extend it
